# Are there any Java HTML parsers where the generated Nodes retain indexes to the original text?

Tags: java, html, xml, parsing, xpath

I'd like to query a HTML document as XML (e.g. with XPath), so I need to pass the HTML through some form of HTML cleaner.

But I'd also like to make modifications to the *original* source string based on the results of the queries.

Is there a Java HTML parser around that retains indexes to the original source string, so I can locate a node and modify the correct part of the original string?

Cheers.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to work with the DOM and then convert it into a String representation? You'll have a cleaner version of the HTML along with your changes. Is there a specific reason that you need to modify the original source string?

Comment: I can think of one.  It makes it easier to figure out what substantive modifications have been made if you don't have to wade through a bunch of textual changes that are just a result of the unparser rendering the XML a bit differently.

Comment: Vivin - I'm trying to 'clean' certain sensitive items from HTML pages so that I can run other parsing tests against the original HTML (with the sensitive data overwritten with 999 or xxx etc).
Also, I want different tests to be able to run in both Java and Javascript, so the original source is the best starting point for me, as the Java HTML parsers and each browser's HTML parser may result in different DOMs (even though they probably shouldn't).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like Jericho is almost exactly what you want.  It is a robust HTML parser designed specifically for making unintrusive modifications to the source document.

While it doesn't come with DOM, SAX, or StAX interfaces, it has custom APIs that are similar enough to those standards that you should be able to adapt your approach to them fairly easily, or write an adapter between whatever you are using and Jericho.  For instance, you can do XPath queries on Jericho documents using Jaxen -- see [this blog entry](http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2009/04/xpath-over-html-using-jericho-and-jaxen.html) for an example.

Jericho has [begin](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/javadoc/net/htmlparser/jericho/Segment.html#getBegin%28%29) and end attributes for every element, and even for parts of the element like the tag name or even an attribute name, so you can edit the document yourself with that information, but where Jericho really shines is the OutputDocument class, which lets you specify replacements directly by calling the appropriate methods with the Jericho elements that match your query instead of having to explicitly call getBegin() and getEnd() on them and pass that to some replacement method.

Comment: I'll also check this out. Thanks. I'll come back and answer each when I've tried them out.

Answer (score 1):

We use [jericho html parser](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/) to do the parsing and [htmlcleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/) to do the actual clean up.

We had problems with jericho's behavior within a server app ( memory management, logging ) that we fixed. (the original developer didn't think our issues were important enough to put in the main code branch). [Our fork is on github.](https://github.com/amplafi/jericho-html)
We also made [fixes to htmlcleaner](https://github.com/amplafi/htmlcleaner).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the "retain indexes to the original text" part but [Jericho](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html) is a very good HTML parser library.

Here is an example of how to remove every span from a html:

```java
public static String removeSpans(String html) {
    Source source = new Source(html);
    source.fullSequentialParse();
    OutputDocument outputDocument = new OutputDocument(source);
    List<Tag> tags = source.getAllTags();
    for (Tag tag : tags) {
        String tagname = tag.getName().toLowerCase();
        if (tagname.equals("span")) {
            //remove the <span>
            outputDocument.remove(tag);
        }
    }
    return outputDocument.toString();
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, but this answer isn't relevant to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use [HTML Parser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/).

You can get indexes to original [Page](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/htmlparser/lexer/Page.html) using [getStartPosition()](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/htmlparser/Node.html#getStartPosition%28%29) and [getEndPosition()](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/htmlparser/Node.html#getEndPosition%28%29) from class [Node](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/htmlparser/Node.html).

Comment: Will check this out and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, you probably want to render the DOM. This basically just means constructing the node tree, it wont alter the document source unless you use an HTML cleaner like [jTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/). Then you have easy access to the document and can modify it as required. I would suggest [DOM4J](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/), it has a good api and xpath support too.

Re your "indexing" requirement, during your traversal/querying of the document you can cache in a list or map any elements or nodes that you wish to modify the text of at a later point.

Answer (score 0):

this works great

http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/

EXAMPLE

```
Tidy tidy = new Tidy(); // obtain a new Tidy instance
tidy.setXHTML(boolean xhtml); // set desired config options using tidy setters 
...                           // (equivalent to command line options)

tidy.parse(inputStream, System.out);
```

For crawling the DOM, i recommend using JDOM, its way faster then simple XML.

http://www.jdom.org/

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory =
DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.newDocument();
Element root = doc.createElement("root");
Text text = doc.createText("This is the root");
root.appendChild(text);
doc.appendChild(root);
```

As far as implementation is concerned i would make a new document, and add nodes to it from the source.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) with an [HTML grammar](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/HTML).

You could take (at least) 2 approaches - try and use it as an actual HTML parser, and then get the indexes into the original string that you are interested in.

Or, it also has built-in support for doing in-place transformations on source text, where you define the transformations that you want to perform on the text as part of the grammar.